# datetime passing to reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I got an error:

The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 0

Comment: Did you get this error out of nowhere, or was there some code involved?

Comment: Thanks for replying:  I am passing report parameters StartDate, EndDate to get list of PatientNames, it gives me the list alright. Then I selected one of the PatientNames and click View button to view report, it gives me the error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

Comment: in your database, is your date value a datetime or nvarchar?

Answer (score 0):

Ron, you have to parse the data since it's of type nvarchar.

For example:

DataTable dt = GetData();

DateTime startDate;

DateTime.TryParse(dt.Rows[0]["StartDate"].ToString(), out startDate);